# How do I produce a status that can be displayed via the badge from a github action?

Tags: github-actions

I've defined a github action and it runs successfully on every push and every pull request, completing with a green check mark when tests pass.

However it never produces a status, or at any rate the github status badge always says "no status."

In addition, I am unable to choose this action as a precondition for merging pull requests because it has no status and so cannot be chosen via the "Require status checks to pass before merging" selector.

Am I trying to do something that just can't be done without explicitly emitting a status via the github API, or is there a more straightforward way to attach a github action as a precondition to a PR merging?

The github action is here: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml

And I'm using this markup for the badge:

```
![Unit Tests](https://github.com/github/docs/actions/workflows/main.yml/badge.svg)
```

(This is an open source repository, so everything is available for inspection.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've added a badge with the example URL instead of customising it with your username and repo:

```
![Unit Tests](https://github.com/github/docs/actions/workflows/main.yml/badge.svg)
```

(It's weird it picked up the name of the action correctly.)

You need to replace that URL with

```
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/actions/workflows/main.yml/badge.svg
```

(Where by "you need" I mean "I sent you [this PR](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/pull/3580)".)

Comment: OK, color me embarrassed! I should have seen that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries!  This is exactly the sort of bug I'd be tearing my own hair out over :P